# dc.js LineChart Aggregated by Month/Year

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I trying to plot a lineChart and I want to aggregate data by Month. I am using dataset from [crossfilter documentation](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference) with slight modification in date.

This is how my dataset looks like:

```
var data = [
  {date: "2011-11-14T16:17:54Z", quantity: 2, total: 190, tip: 100, type: "tab"},
  {date: "2011-07-10T16:28:54Z", quantity: 1, total: 300, tip: 200, type: "visa"},
  {date: "2011-07-15T16:28:54Z", quantity: 1, total: 300, tip: 200, type: "visa"},
  {date: "2011-06-14T16:30:43Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
  {date: "2011-06-14T16:48:46Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
  {date: "2011-05-14T16:53:41Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
  {date: "2011-07-17T16:14:06Z", quantity: 1, total: 100, tip: 0, type: "cash"},
  {date: "2011-05-14T16:58:03Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
  {date: "2011-12-14T17:07:21Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
  {date: "2011-11-14T17:22:59Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
  {date: "2011-11-14T17:25:45Z", quantity: 2, total: 200, tip: 0, type: "cash"},
  {date: "2011-11-14T17:29:52Z", quantity: 1, total: 200, tip: 100, type: "visa"}
];
```

I want to group total by Month-Year. My Data Group is returning total based on date instead of Month.

[image]

In my graph, July 10, 15 and 17 are plotted as different point. I want to combine them all into July-2017 points. How do I acheive that ? Any pointers?
Thanks All!

here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/usingh2buffaloedu/8u0etnwd/

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had issues with time rendering in dc.js, but in your example the key is to get the month values in your dimension.

```
var dateDimension = facts.dimension(function (d) {return d3.time.month(d.newDate); });
```

See the updated fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/ury1k1bs/1/)

I think the .round() chart method is only useful for brushing, not for rendering.

For more see the time interval example provided by dc.js...
http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/switching-time-intervals.html